# Conditional probability given only an average

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, quantum-information

I’ve been working on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282320/pnn-given-pnn-and-overline-n) question, which I found on physics.SE. Unfortunately it was closed because it’s a homework question, but I’d like to get more of a hint than the original poster got.

I know that I’m supposed to use Bayes’ Theorem, but I don’t see how I’m supposed to use the fact that $\bar{N}$ is known. Every effort so far has yielded an unwieldy fraction that can’t be simplified.

Edit: Apparently I'm supposed to copy/paste the question. Here it is:

This is one of the exercises of Barnett's book on [quantum information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282320/pnn-given-pnn-and-overline-n).

A particle counter records counts with an efficiency $\eta$. This means that each particle is detected with probability $\eta$ and missed with probability $1-\eta$. Let $N$ be the number of particles present and $n$ be  the number of detected. 
Then:
\begin{equation}
P(n|N)=\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}\eta^n (1-\eta)^{N-n}
\end{equation}

I know the mean number of particle present is:

\begin{equation}
\bar{N}=\sum N P(N)
\end{equation}

I want to calculate $P(N|n)$. I'm stuck here by a while, so I do not know how to proceed.

Edit 2: I'm adding a screenshot of the question in question:

[image]

Comment: Please don't link a closed question. Copy the relevant (only math) parts here.

Comment: @leonbloy I didn't know that was a rule, sorry. I've copied it now.

Comment: "I want to calculate (|)" To do so, you are missing some information, for example the (unconditional) distribution of N would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely know that

$$ P(N|n) = \frac{P(n|N) P(N)}{P(n)}=\frac{P(n|N) P(N)}{\sum_N P(n|N) P(N)}$$

This tells you that you $P(n|N)$ is not enough, you need $P(N)$. To understand this should be your starting point.

Now, here, you only give us the mean of $N$ (actually you wrote the general formula of the expected value, but I guess you meant that you know $\bar{N}$). Still not enough.

Perhaps there is some implicit statistical model for $N$ that you've missed? Perhaps (just guessing) it follows a Poisson distribution? If so, you are done, because the Poisson distribution depends on a single parameter (which is the mean), hence you indeed can write $P(N)$.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the exact question from the textbook. Unfortunately, doing this same calculation for a Poisson distribution was part (a) of the question. Do you have any other thoughts, given this?

Comment: No, I don't see how one could do with the mean alone.